# Install directory of Android service

Tags: android, service, adb

I am analyzing a custom Android device. I tried to enumerate services running in the system (`adb shell service list`) and I found out that there is a service (let's call it `MyService`) that I would like to analyze more in depth. It might be a privileged (system) service, if that is a relevant information.

When I run `adb shell service list | grep MyService`, it returns something like `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.MyService`. I would like to get the code/binary/APK of this service. However, when I run `adb shell pm path aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.MyService`, it returns error code 1 and doesn't print any path. The same situation occurs when I execute `adb shell pm list packages | grep -i XXX`, where `XXX` is any of `aaa`,`bbb`,`ccc`,`ddd` or `MyService` (for the record, `aaa` and `bbb` return some packages, but they do not have anything in common with the specific service).

**My question is:** How can I extract the code/binary/APK/... of the service?  How do I find where it is installed?

*If root access is needed, that shouldn't be a problem.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to this problem as well, and had some fun exploring the Android internals. Eventually, I was only able to find the process id that provides the service, and any information associated with that, through `/proc` and `/sys` VFS.

Here are my findings:

My first discovery was that, `dumpsys <SERVICE_SHORT_NAME>` can connect to any service, and ask it to dump its internal state. But this doesn't always include the package name or install directory for that service. I decided to trace system calls from this `dumpsys` program, using `strace`. But it turns out that IPC happens through a non-standard `/dev/binder` device that `strace` doesn't understand:

```
$ su
# strace -f -y dumpsys telephony_ims | grep binder | tail 
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/binder", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC) = 3</dev/binder>
ioctl(3</dev/binder>, BINDER_VERSION, 0x7fd88906b4) = 0
ioctl(3</dev/binder>, BINDER_SET_MAX_THREADS, 0x7fd88906a8) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1040384, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_NORESERVE, 3</dev/binder>, 0) = 0x7990b83000
ioctl(3</dev/binder>, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fd8890460) = 0
ioctl(3</dev/binder>, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fd8890110) = 0
[pid 15836] ioctl(3</dev/binder>, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7990b7e8a0) = 0
[pid 15836] ioctl(3</dev/binder>, BINDER_WRITE_READ <unfinished ...>
[pid 15836] ioctl(3</dev/binder>, BINDER_THREAD_EXIT, 0) = 0
```

Luckily, there is still a method to trace what happens inside this binder device. With the help from [this other Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457589/android-binder-tracing), I was able to find the pid running any service.

I will examine the service `telephony_ims` as an example.

- Please run the following commands as root.
- First, we need to set up Android Binder Tracing, using commands from the other Stack Overflow page.

  - `cd /sys/kernel/debug/tracing; echo > set_event; echo 1 > events/binder/enable; echo 1 > tracing_on`
- Then, we must run `dumpsys`, and immediately afterwards, read the trace logs.

  - Prerequisite: I used `less` command, which isn't available on all android devices. If your bash cannot find `less`, then you could dump the results to a file on SD Card, and open it using a text viewer.
  - Run `(cat /proc/uptime; dumpsys telephony_ims >/dev/null & echo $!; cat /proc/uptime; cat /sys/kernel/debug/trace | tail -n 1000) | less`
- Look at the resulting output

  - The first three lines are

    ```
    16682.46 92635.05
    20823
    16682.47 92635.12
    ```
  - Search for `20823` from the second line, which is the PID of `dumpsys`. (The first and third lines are start time timestamp, and end time timestamp, respectively)
  - Found out that `dumpsys` is talking with `servicemanager`:

    ```
    dumpsys-20823 [006] .... 16682.479173: binder_transaction: transaction=10738057 dest_node=1 dest_proc=563  # more content afterwards, ignored. pid 563 is "servicemanager"
    # ... more lines ...
    servicemanager-563   [003] .... 16682.479283: binder_transaction: transaction=10738058 dest_node=0 dest_proc=20823 # more content afterwards, ignored.
    ```
  - Then, it turns out that `dumpsys-20823` started a child process, 20827:

    ```
         dumpsys-20823 [004] .... 16682.479808: binder_return: cmd=0x7206 BR_TRANSACTION_COMPLETE
         dumpsys-20823 [004] .... 16682.479810: binder_transaction_received: transaction=10738061
         dumpsys-20823 [004] .... 16682.479811: binder_return: cmd=0x80407203 BR_REPLY
         dumpsys-20823 [004] .... 16682.479812: binder_read_done: ret=0
         dumpsys-20823 [004] .... 16682.479813: binder_ioctl_done: ret=0
         dumpsys-20827 [006] .... 16682.480058: binder_ioctl: cmd=0xc0306201 arg=0x780a5668a0
         dumpsys-20827 [006] .... 16682.480060: binder_command: cmd=0x40406300 BC_TRANSACTION
         dumpsys-20827 [006] .... 16682.480077: binder_transaction: transaction=10738063 dest_node=29113 dest_proc=2574 dest_thread=0 reply=0 flags=0x10 code=0x5f444d50
    ```
  - Eventually, it's this child process who gave away the PID of the service ("dest_proc=**2574**"):

    ```
    dumpsys-20827 [006] .... 16682.480077: binder_transaction: transaction=10738063 dest_node=29113 dest_proc=2574 dest_thread=0 reply=0 flags=0x10 code=0x5f444d50
    ```
- Look into this process for its package name / related jars and apks

  ```
  $ ps -A | grep 2574
  radio          2574    875 14414052 120280 SyS_epoll_wait     0 S com.android.phone
  $ ls -l /proc/2574/fd | egrep 'apk|jar' | head
  lr-x------ 1 root root 64 2020-12-15 13:42 10 -> /apex/com.android.art/javalib/bouncycastle.jar
  lr-x------ 1 root root 64 2020-12-15 13:42 102 -> /system/app/Stk/Stk.apk
  lr-x------ 1 root root 64 2020-12-15 13:42 11 -> /apex/com.android.art/javalib/apache-xml.jar
  lr-x------ 1 root root 64 2020-12-15 13:42 12 -> /system/framework/framework.jar
  lr-x------ 1 root root 64 2020-12-15 13:42 13 -> /system/framework/ext.jar
  lr-x------ 1 root root 64 2020-12-15 13:42 14 -> /system/framework/telephony-common.jar
  lr-x------ 1 root root 64 2020-12-15 13:42 15 -> /system/framework/voip-common.jar
  lr-x------ 1 root root 64 2020-12-15 13:42 16 -> /system/framework/ims-common.jar
  lr-x------ 1 root root 64 2020-12-15 13:42 18 -> /system/framework/framework-atb-backward-compatibility.jar
  lr-x------ 1 root root 64 2020-12-15 13:42 19 -> /apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar
  ```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! I didn't even think about the possibility to trace the dumpsys command...